# What credential is my server looking for?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, samba, windows-10, nas

For the past few months, I have been using a NAS server that I created by running FreeNAS in a VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. I know this isn't ideal, so I set up Samba shares on my server. Now, when I want to access that server from Windows 10, I go to the network tab and click on the name of my server. A pop-up appears, and it asks me for my Network Credentials. I have tried every imaginable username and password, I have gone into Windows credential manager and added every type of credential for the server posible. No matter what I do, it still says that my username or password is incorrect. I feel like I'm missing something important, but I have no idea what it is. If someone has run into the same issue, please let me know. I want to use Ubuntu services instead of some crazy VirtualBox one. Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `sudo smbpasswd -a <username>` on the server? Samba uses a separate set of passwords to authenticate. (It can be the same password though)

Comment: Yes. it was the same as my main password, but yes. I think the issue is in Windows credentials, because in my FreeNAS setup, I can access it as a computer, and inside there is a folder that is my NAS.

Comment: Is the user designated as a valid user in smb conf?

Comment: That is done by adding a line to the share designation such as `valid users = user`

Comment: Yes, "valid user" is my ubuntu username. Should it be my Windows one?

Comment: If they are different, you should enter the credentials that are setup on the server. So try logging in with the Ubuntu username when asked for credentials.

Comment: I tried that, and it still doesn't let me in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same username / password in windows and samba, when asked for credentials, just enter your username and **no password**.  This did the trick for me (after long search).